# Controller Scaffholding fails with exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have updated to Visual Studio 2013 update 5 and now I cannot scaffold controllers when I try to scaffold a controller, I get the following error:

There was an error running the selected code generator:
'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

1. I uninstalled/install entity Fwk
2. I switched my providers to SQL
   instead of MySQL (to correct another bug)
3. I put
   base.onModelCreating() at the end of the OnModelCreating()
4. My context inherits : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)

Comment: `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation` is a broad message. Post exception details and stack trace to find out which real error was thrown.

Comment: Hi Tetsuya, Where can I find the stack trace of this?

Comment: Can you embed exception image/screenshot in your question (probably you may find stack trace there)? Sounds that `connectionString` information to point the model cannot be read by scaffolding mechanism.